# Grammar and quality check for a Klingon warning notice for server room

Tags: star-trek, klingon-language

I am writing a tri-lingual sign for my personal server room (English, Klingon and Matoran). I know a few words in Klingon and some of the basic grammar e.g. (OVS sentence structure). I also possess the boQwi' program for my qoqyoq portable computer device.

What i am trying to say is.

> WARNING
>
> Servers in operation
>
> If you shut down the servers, the sysadmin will be very angry with you

This is what I have.

> SoH ghuHmoH jIH! (lit. "I warn you!")
>
> Qap De'toy'wI'! ("De'toy'wi'" is my translation of server. lit. one who serves data)
>
> De'toy'wi' bochu'Ha'chugh SoH, De'wi'patloHwi' DuQeH ghaH! (De'wi'patloH is my translation of sysadmin. lit. "Computer System Administrator")

IS my sign understandable to those who speak Klingon (the warriors tongue).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic here, but I can't think of anywhere else where it could possibly be a better fit. It's certainly an unusual type of question for this site, but you never know—you might get a good answer or two!

Comment: What about the linguistics community?

Comment: Given the number of Klingon experts that frequent these boards, I think we can anticipate that you'll get a solid answer, if the question doesn't get closed first.

Comment: @Escoce Translation request and grammar checks are off topic on Linguistics, as far as I recall.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it was just another equally topical possibility.

Comment: Interestingly, fictional languages [are on-topic on Linguistics.SE](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/433/2722), but I don’t know about grammar-checking questions. Pretty sure there are probably more Klingon experts on this Stack though.

Comment: warriorcodereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: [Fictional language are also on-topic on Sci-Fi](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8166/translations-of-fictional-languages-to-english), according to the responses/votes on meta. If this one gets closed, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Will the Matoran contain "Warning: Bohrok containment unit!"?

Comment: This question demonstrates one of the reasons why I love this site. This is the only place I can think of where someone would come to check their Klingon translations :D

Comment: You of course need a copy of der blinkenlights posted too - "ACHTUNG! Alles touristen und non-technischen peepers!

  Das machine control is nicht fur gerfinger-poken und
  mittengrabben. Oderwise is easy schnappen der springenwerk,
  blowen fuse, und poppencorken mit spitzensparken.
  Der machine is diggen by experten only. Is nicht fur
  geverken by das dummkopfen. Das rubbernecken sightseenen
  keepen das cotten picken hands in das pockets,
  so relaxen und watchen das blinkenlights."

Answer (score 23):

You're on the right track! Needs some work, though.

**SoH ghuHmoH jIH!**
means
"You're. The view screen warns!"

Klingon pronouns are absorbed by pronomial prefixes:
**qaghuHmoH!**
= "I warn you!"

You could also go with **yIghuH!** ("Be aware!"). Alternatively: **yIqIm!** ("Pay attention!")

The word **toy'wI'** means "servant". Somebody who serves something - a waiter, or server - is a **jabwI'**.

However, I'd recommend something like **HablI'** ("data transceiving device"). Maybe **DaH pa'vamDaq QaptaH HablI'mey.** ("Data transceiving devices are currently operating in this room.")

**De'toy'wi' bochu'Ha'chugh SoH, De'wi'patloHwi' DuQeH ghaH!**

You've clearly done your homework and made an honest attempt, but this means something like "If you (plural) shut of the data-servant, you (singular are), the computer system admin, he/she will be angry at you."

I'd recommend:

**HablI' Dachu'Ha'chugh, De'wI' pat loHwI' DaQeHqu'moHbej.**
= "If you deactivate a data transceiver, you will certainly make the computer system admin very angry."

### Edit:

Some people have - quite fairly - asked for some sort of support to back up my claims. Unfortunately, it's a bit hard to source a translation; my source is my own knowledge of the language.

Instead, I figure I'll gloss my text, so that people can easily verify it for themselves.

**yIghuH!** = "Be aware!"

**yI**- = imperative verb prefix; used when the object is third-person singular, or when the subject/listener is singular and there is no object (as in this case)

**ghuH** = "prepare for, be alerted to" (defined on p.88 of *The Klingon Dictionary*)

**HablI' Dachu'Ha'chugh, De'wI' pat loHwI' DaQeHqu'moHbej.**
= "If you deactivate it, you will certainly anger the computer system administrator greatly."

**HablI'** = "data transceiving device" (defined on p.88 of *The Klingon Dictionary*)

**Da**- = verb prefix used when the subject is second-person singular and the object is third-person

**chu'Ha'** = **chu'** + -**Ha'** = "activate" + *undo* = "deactivate" (see for example the sentence **yIchu'Ha'** ("Disengage it!") on page 49 in *The Klingon Dictionary*)

-**chugh** = type-9 verb suffix: *if* (TKD §4.2.9)

**Dachu'Ha'chugh** = "if you (singular) deactivate it/him/her/them"

Klingon is Object-Verb-Subject, so **HablI' Dachu'Ha'chugh** means "If you deactivate a/the data transceiving device(s)"

**De'wI'** = "computer" (TKD p.85)

**pat** (TKD p.100; compare **jolpat* ("transporter system") and **'ul pat mutlhwI'** ("electrician, electric system assembler"))

**loHwI'** = **loH** + -**wI'** = "administer" (TKD p.94) + "one who does" = "administrator"

In Klingon, a sequence of nouns *X Y Z* means "the A pertaining to Y pertaining to X" (TKD §3.4 *The noun-noun construction*). So, **De'wI' pat loHwI'** = "computer system administrator".

**Da**- = verb prefix used when the subject is second-person singular and the object is third-person

**QeH** = "be angry" (TKD p.104)

-**qu'** = emphasis verb suffix rover (TKD §3.4)

-**moH** = type-4 verb suffix: *cause* (TKD §4.2.4)

-**bej** = type-6 verb suffix: *definitely* (TKD §4.2.6)

**DaQeHqu'moHbej** = "you certainly make her/him/it/them very angry"

So, **De'wI' pat loHwI' DaQeHqu'moHbej** means "you certainly anger the computer system administrator".

Comment: I'm in no position to argue the validity of the answer. It's not that I don't trust you, however, some indication as to the source of information above would be nice :)

Comment: +1 just for being convincing and looking like you know what you're talking about (even though realistically, I haven't the faintest idea if anything you said is true).

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately it's a bit hard to source a language that's been continuously evolved for 30 years; my primary source is myself, a speaker since 2006. Tomorrow I'll try to find time to go through the teanslation in detail, to make it easier for readers to verify my claims.

Comment: (( For the record, @NKCampbell’s comment wasn’t there when I was typing—looks like we decided to comment almost the exact same thing about 22 seconds apart. Just to make it clear I wasn’t trying to double-ambush you or anything. :-) ))

Comment: No problem; it's a perfectly understandable request :)

Comment: As the author of the {boQwI'} program referred to in the original question, I certify that his answer is correct Klingon and means what he says it means.

Comment: One detail: you write that _da-_ represents 2pl/3 (subject second person plural, object third person), but in the translation of _Dachu'Hachugh_ (gesundheit), you write “if you (singular)…”. Was that meant to read “if you (plural)…”, then?

Comment: Oops, that was a mistake on my part! Da- is 2sg/3, not 2pl/3. I'll edit that.

Comment: Hopefully the OP will accept this answer. I can't imagine a more thorough and well-crafted answer. +1

Comment: I feel like the Klingon version should focus more on the dishonor it would cause for the person shutting down the servers.